# Can't add background image on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am building a game that runs on a background image. The image is located at the path `../images/bg.jpg`.

```
-images
  -bg.jpg
-src
  -elements
    - source.js
  - map.js
  - main.js
```

Now in my `map.js`, I am going to use the image as a background pattern and make a background for my game.

Here is my code:

In my map, there is an init method where I initialize the background property using

```
this.background = new Image();
```

then in the `render()` method of my map, I do this:

```
this.ctx.save();
this.background.addEventListener('load', function() {

  var pattern = this.ctx.createPattern(background, 'repeat');
  this.ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10000, 10000);
});
this.background.src = "../images/bg.jpg";
this.ctx.restore();
```

In my `main.js` I call `map.render()`,

but the map doesn't show a background picture. What is wrong with my code?

**EDIT:**

Now my code has changed to this:

```
this.ctx.save();
var drawBackground = function () {
      alert('Hit me');
      var pattern = this.ctx.createPattern(background, 'repeat');
      this.ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
      this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10000, 10000);
    }

    this.background.addEventListener('load', drawBackground, false);
    this.background.src = "../images/bg.jpg";
    this.ctx.restore();
```

But no miracle has happened and I don't receive the 'Hit me' alert. I am so confused.

**NEW EDIT:**

It seems to be a path issue which I have managed to resolve by placing the image to the correct folder. This is because I am using `webpack` plugin with `Node.js` and the `webpack` plugin doesn't know where to put my background image in the build folder if I don't tell it specifically.

At last I used a plugin called `copy-webpack-plugin` to copy my static files to the build directory and then using the stylesheet solution the background image can be displayed.

However this is not the effect I want.

In my game I have a very large background and I want the background look exactly like the ground, as if I drop something on the ground, when I move away, that thing will stay at the same spot of the ground.

But if I set the background image in stylesheet that thing I just dropped will move away from the spot when I move my mouse to the other end of the frame. How can I make the objects stay on the same spot of the background not just the same x and y coordinates? The background image is very small so I am making it displayed repeatedly until it fills the canvas. I guess what I just described can only be achieved by javascript codes?

Here is a picture to explain my thoughts on the expected background:

[image]

For example if we look at the picture above, the background image contains a moon, and I have drawn some stars on top of the background. In the left picture my mouse is at the bottom right corner of the screen. Now I move my mouse, and the frame moves too because I want to show how I go to the other end of the canvas. Picture on the right shows my mouse is now at the top right of the frame, which means my mouse has moved towards the top. Now the star and the moon keep their relative positions but their y coordinates should be underneath my mouse's.

Comment: Do you get any error? Do you call `render`  inside a loop? What does the `this` keyword refer to? If it's not the window, then the `this` inside your load callback might not be what you think it is.

Comment: Also, because you're using an `async` function, the `.save()` and `.restore()` are both called before you draw anything.

Comment: @Cristy No I don't see any error in server side or in my development tool console. `this` refers to the Map object. Which function is `async` function?How can I fix this? I am new to javascript. The `render()` method is called by a method `animate()` in the `main.js` via `requestAnimationFrame`. Previously the `Map#render()` method drew a bunch of rectangle blocks to form a background but now I want to replace it with background images but don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a static (meaning not a scrolling image ), it's as easy as doing this in your CSS

```
.your-canvas { 
   background:url("../images/bg.jpg"); 
}
```

Comment: I've tried but this won't display the background either. It's just black background. I wonder if the background is covered by the black color but I can't see any.

Comment: your suggestion only works on my small test example with a single html file. However in my code I have a directory of javascript files and they call functions in other files.

Comment: This is the recommended and a very performant way to display static backgrounds.

Comment: OK see my latest EDIT. I am able to display the background but the effect is not what I want. What if I still want to display it using javascript?

Comment: hello @newguy , sorry that I'm writing this late. I'm not sure if I understood the problem correctly, but in your CSS you can try .thing-you-drop{ position: fixed; } , still not sure if I understood your edit correctly.

Comment: @CihanKöseoğlu I have posted another question and answered myself there. It is a bit tricky. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786172/cannot-load-image-using-webpack-dev-server-in-nodejs