# Cannot load image using webpack dev server in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Hi I am using the following code to try to draw a background for my game, but I keep getting the failure message and I couldn't figure out why this would happen.

This is my `main.js`:

```
this.background = new Image();

var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

var loaded = false;

var drawBackground = function () {

  loaded = true;

  var pattern = context.createPattern(this.background, 'repeat');
  context.fillStyle = pattern;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 10000, 10000);
}

this.background.onload = drawBackground;
this.background.src = "../images/bg.jpg";

setTimeout(function() {
  if (loaded) {
    console.log('success');
  } else {
    console.log('falilure');
  }
}, 3000);
```

My file directory structure looks like this:

```
- dist
  - static
    - bg.jpg
  - bundle.js
- images
   - bg.jpg
- src
  - main.js
- server.js
```

I have tried changing `this.background.src` to `./static/bg.jpg` but it still doesn't work.

I am running my code on a webpack-dev-server using the command `npm run dev`. In production the source code and static files will be copied and bundled to `dist` directory. But I am using the development mode so I guess the image is not copied yet. Why is my image not loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution for this after tweaking for a day. I have made several mistakes in my code.

To load the image in webpack-dev-server we need to use loaders configured in webpack.config.js (or whatever name you give to the config file of webpack-dev-server).

So I put the loader definition inside the module section like this:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
      },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=90000' } 
    ]
  },
```

Now here comes the tricky part, using the loader alone doesn't get your image displayed. You have to require it as a resource in javascript code. So in the question code I need to change

```
this.background.src = "../images/bg.jpg";
```

to this:

```
this.background.src = require('../images/bg.jpg');
```

But that still doesn't work, because I was using async calls on synchronous model.
I need to change the onload call to receive a callback and draw images in the callback. Then the code finally works. And it would look like this:

```
var image = this.background;
var _canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
this.ctx = _canvas.getContext('2d');
var drawBackground = function (callback) {      
      callback(this);
}

image.onload = drawBackground(() => {
  let pattern = this.ctx.createPattern(image, 'repeat');
  this.ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, _canvas.width, _canvas.height);
});
image.src = require('../images/bg.jpg');
```